# How to Protect My Download Links

Tags: wordpress, plugins, download

Some one please help , I have started a site, and want to have my downloads which could not be copied by some one else , I have given the below link of someones site which has a download link in it which is not copy-able,

The link is like : http://188.138.69.43/Oceanofgames.com/Door_To_Door.iso?

But when you copy and paste in your site it does not work. I need just the same. how is it possible? Kindly guide me a little.

Check the Download link:: http://oceanofgames.com/door-to-door-pc-game-free-download/

How he have done it if you could please tell me!